# Modify the manufacturing order workflow in odoo 9

Tags: workflow, odoo-9

I want to modify the workflow of the manufacturing order in odoo 9. but when i activate the developer mode, the field that contains the dropdown list where we can find "Edit workflow" is not displayed.

how we can display it???

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Anything that you've tried already?

Comment: i don t tried any code yet. just the odoo dropdown list where we can choose a "edit workflow" option is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the odoo 9. when we activate the developer mode,there is like a "ladybird" that well be added to the header (where there is the installed modules). we click on the ladybird and we will get the list of the different options ( where we can modify the workflow).